# Laravel: retrieve count of value in JSON array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Iv currently taken over a project where the developer has stored `has many` relationships in json array columns in certain tables.

product table

```
----------------------------
id | product | colour
----------------------------
 1   iPhone    ["8","4","1"]
 2   iPad      ["8","1"]
 3   Macbook   ["8"]
```

This is an example of the relationships stored between a product and product colours available.

I need to be able to get the count of products, related to a certian colour. 
So in this example... `colour: 8` would return `3 products`

I am use to Eloquent relationships utilising `$product->colours()` but unfortunately in this instance i can't do that, and i am unable to change the current db structure.

How would i be able to get the amount of products per certain colour using eloquent where or whereIn clauses?

What i have tried so far...

```
$count = $products->where('colour', '[$colour->id]')->count();
----
$count = $products->whereIn('colour', $colour->id)->count();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you fired the "developer" that did such a mess of "relationship"

Comment: $count = $products->where('colour', $colour->id)->count(); ?

Comment: @Amarnasan when i saw the database i almost had a heart attack, no pivot tables for hasMany relationships.

Comment: @JérémyCasper i have already tried that, returns an empty array

Comment: I think this developer missed the whole point of eloquent relationships

Comment: $count = $products->where('colour', 'LIKE', '%'.$colour->id.'%')->count();

Comment: @ochii, your comment is like my answer, but you are missing the double quotation character. If you dont' include it, a product with color code '18' will be accepted when looking for code '8', since 8 is included in 18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ugly, but I guess it works:

```
\App\Product::where('colour','like','%"' .$colour->id '"%')->distinct()->count()
```

Comment: That would return 8, 18, 228,... for query='8'. Normalization with `colors` table would be a must imho. Eventually json field instead of string.

Comment: @Tpojka No, it wouldn't.... because of the double quotes surrounding the color code. Read before ranting.

Comment: What would return `%8%`?

Comment: @Tpojka What would return %"8"% ? Still don't get it?